# Hyundai Coupe 2005 replaced battery and horn, indicators and wipers on constant. will not start

Tags: battery, starting, maintenance, accessories, hyundai-coupe

Car wont start after battery replacement. Horn blowing constantly. Also indicators and wipers are on constantly.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: If you have an electronic key, try pressing the different buttons on it.  Sometimes when the ECM gets one of those signals (alarm, lock or unlock), it will notice that an authorized person is nearby, and come back to its senses.

Answer (score 0):

When you replace a battery, some cars’ computers reset. There is likely some secret code you have to enter into the dash while the key is in Acc. Google Hyundai coupe ECM reset.